# Value Error: Could not broadcast input Array from shape (29, 84, 3) into shape (100,100,3)?

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing

I have the following python code to resize an image:

```
def preprocess(self, img):
    width, height = self.__get_dataset_image_size(self.dataset_name)
    out = np.ndarray(shape=(1, height, width, 3), dtype='uint8')
    out[0, ...] = np.asarray(img)
    return out
```

I used this already before with other images of shape (x, y, 3) and it was working.

But now I tried it again and it doesn' t.

Can someone tell me what I'm missing?

Comment: you're missing a resampling of your image. it's simply not the size that is required. -- DO NOT use np.resize, that resizes an array by dropping or padding, but it doesn't **resample** it. OpenCV's `cv.resize` would resample an image. scikit-image also has methods. -- and you should get more familiar with numpy, so you understand this error.

Answer (score 0):

When you blit an array to another in numpy, both must have the same shape. Your "out" array is of the shape (100, 100, 3) and your image is of the shape (19, 84, 3).

You can do this instead so numpy only tries to edit the elements within the size of the image:
`out[0:height, 0:width] = np.asarray(img)`